# Connecting to Revolut sandbox

Tags: authorization, auth0, jwt

I'm trying to create a client connection to Revolut. I'm following their [tutorial](https://revolutdev.github.io/business-api/#getting-started), however im'm stuck at **Exchange Authorisation Code**.

What i have done so far:

1. Created business account on their [sanbox](https://sandbox-business.revolut.com/)
2. Added my public key here https://sandbox-business.revolut.com/settings/api
3. Activated my API Certificate via **Enable API access to your account**(i went through all the steps and got information that access is now enabled), however i can still see `Access is not enabled` on my API certificate
4. created JWT token and signed it with my private key (verified it with https://jwt.io/)
5. send request for access token like this (done via postman):

   ```
   curl --request POST \
     --url https://sandbox-b2b.revolut.com/api/1.0/auth/token \
     --header 'Accept: */*' \
     --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
     --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
     --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
     --header 'Content-Length: 596' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     --header 'Host: sandbox-b2b.revolut.com' \
     --header 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
     --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
     --data 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=oa_sand_xxx&client_id=xxx&client_assertion_type=xxx&client_assertion=xxx
   ```

however the response is:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client",
    "error_description": "Incorrect request token"
}
```

Now im not sure it there is something im doing wrong with requesting access token or is it due to step 3, where it seems that activation of my API Certificates went fine but then i see it as not activated. Could you verify my steps to help me determine where the issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out Authorisation Code is valid 2 min only, after that time you have to request another one.

Comment: Each time I generate a new Code, I still receive the same output. What is it that you did to bypass the error?

Comment: My Issue was, I was copying the last empty query string param as well along the generated code. Fixed it.