# Authenticating to Revolut API

Tags: node.js, express, insomnia

I am trying to follow Revolut's tutorial for authenticating to their API and I'm stuck at requesting a reusable access token.

So far I've managed to:
1. Create public/private keys
2. Upload public key
3. Sign a jwt with the generated client_id
4. Get an authorisation code

But I am blocked at using the above for requesting a reusable access token.

As per this [page](https://developer.revolut.com/docs/business-api/#oauth-exchange-authorisation-code), I'm supposed to create a POST request on `https://b2b.revolut.com/api/1.0/auth/token` with the following body:

```
{
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_id": my_client_id,
    "code": my_authorisation_code,
    "client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
    "client_assertion": my_jwt
}
```

Which I've done in Insomnia but I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "client_id is missing"
}
```

Looking on SO for an answer I stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823619/connecting-to-revolut-sandbox), but I get this error all the time, even after I change the client_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the body should not be a JSON, it should have been url encoded, like this:

`grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=client_id&code=code&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=jwt`

Comment: Hey Radu! Thank you for this answer! I've just spent 6 hours debugging it until I got here. They could've mentioned this weird detail in the docs.

Comment: hey @DmitryOgurtsov, no problem, glad it helped, I know how frustrating debugging stuff can be.